# Unable to insert row after inserting the first row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I am working on a user verification form that inserts user's phone number and country into database before verifying. But, after inserting the first row, it does not insert a second row. In my 'user' mysql table, I have 'id' as my primary key with AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
<?php

  class UsersController {

  public $_GB;

  function __construct($_GB)
 {
     $this->_GB = $_GB;
 }

public function VerifyUser($phone, $code, $countryName)
{
    $phone = $this->_GB->_DB->escapeString($phone);
    $countryName = $this->_GB->_DB->escapeString($countryName);

    $app_name = $this->_GB->getSettings('app_name');
    $smsVerification = $this->_GB->getSettings('sms_verification');
    if ($smsVerification == 1) {
        $smsVerification = true;
    } else {
        $smsVerification = false;
    }
    if (!$this->UserExists($phone, $countryName)) {
        // Generating API key
        $auth_token = $this->generateApiKey();


        $arrayData = array(
            'phone' => $phone,
            'auth_token' => $auth_token,
            'status' => 'Hey, follow and add me up on ' . $app_name,
            'status_date' => time(),
            'country' => $countryName,
            'is_activated' => 0,
            'has_backup' => 0,
            'backup_hash' => null

        );
        $result = $this->_GB->_DB->insert('users', $arrayData);
        $newUserID = $this->_GB->_DB->last_Id();
        $this->insertDefaultStatus($newUserID);
        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            $IDResult = $this->_GB->_DB->select('users', '*', "  `phone` = '{$phone}'");
            if ($this->_GB->_DB->numRows($IDResult) > 0) {
                $fetch = $this->_GB->_DB->fetchAssoc($IDResult);
                $res = $this->createCode($fetch['id'], $code);
                if ($res) {
                    // successfully inserted into database
                    if ($smsVerification == true) {
                        $this->verificationCodeMessage($phone, $code);
                    }
                    $array = array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => 'SMS request has been initiated! Please wait, You will be receiving it shortly.',
                        'mobile' => $phone,
                        'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
                        'code' => $code,
                        'hasBackup' => $fetch['has_backup'] == 1 ? true : false
                    );
                    return $array;
                } else {
                    // Failed to create user
                    $array = array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Sorry! Something went wrong.',
                        'mobile' => null,
                        'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
                        'code' => null,
                        'hasBackup' => false
                    );
                    return $array;
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Failed to create user
            $array = array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'SORRY! SOMETHING WENT WRONG2.',
                'mobile' => null,
                'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
                'code' => null,
                'hasBackup' => false
            );
            return $array;

        }
    } else if ($this->UserExists($phone, $countryName)) {
        // User with same phone already existed in the database

        // Generating API key
        $auth_token = $this->generateApiKey();

        $fields = "`auth_token` = '" . $auth_token . "'";
        $fields .= ",`is_activated` = '" . 0 . "'";
        $result = $this->_GB->_DB->update('users', $fields, "`phone` = {$phone}");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            $IDResult = $this->_GB->_DB->select('users', '*', "  `phone` = '{$phone}'");
            if ($this->_GB->_DB->numRows($IDResult) > 0) {
                $fetch = $this->_GB->_DB->fetchAssoc($IDResult);
                $res = $this->createCode($fetch['id'], $code);
                if ($res) {
                    // successfully inserted into database
                    // send sms
                    if ($smsVerification == true) {
                        $this->verificationCodeMessage($phone, $code);
                    }
                    $array = array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'message' => 'SMS request has been initiated! Please wait, You will be receiving it shortly.',
                        'mobile' => $phone,
                        'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
                        'code' => $code,
                        'hasBackup' => $fetch['has_backup'] == 1 ? true : false
                    );
                    return $array;

                } else {
                    // Failed to create user
                    $array = array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Sorry! Something went wrong.',
                        'mobile' => null,
                        'smsVerification' => true,
                        'code' => null,
                        'hasBackup' => false
                    );
                    return $array;

                }
            }

        } else {
            // Failed to create user
            $array = array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry! Something went wrong.',
                'mobile' => null,
                'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
                'code' => null,
                'hasBackup' => false
            );
            return $array;

        }
    } else {
        $array = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry! mobile number is not valid or missing.',
            'mobile' => null,
            'smsVerification' => $smsVerification,
            'code' => null,
            'hasBackup' => false
        );
        return $array;
    }

}

}
```

When I try to verify the first user, it works fine. When verify the first user AGAIN, it successfully updates the user row SINCE IT IS ALREADY EXISTING. But when i try to verify another user, nothing is inserted into database; it only gives me "SORRY! SOMETHING WENT WRONG2"

see my database db.sql.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `UserName` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
   `UserStatus` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `UserState` text NOT NULL,
   `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `auth_token` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   `UserImage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `UserCover` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
   `FullName` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
   `Date` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
   `website` text,
   `reg_id` text,
   `isFollowing` text NOT NULL,
   `status_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `is_activated` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `has_backup` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `backup_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL

     ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`UserName`), ADD KEY `Index_3` (`active`);

 ALTER TABLE `users`
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Unique key not allow repeated same value, check your insert values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a unique key constraint on the UserName but your UserExists function doesn't take it in parameter. Maybe you should check the userName in the UserExists function because if you try to add the same name it will be impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I resolved it be removing the "ADD UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`UserName`), ADD KEY `Index_3` (`active`)" .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to `UPDATE` the record rather than adding a second record for the same user?

See `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.